# Get User Profile Info from Preferred Name

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, spservices

I am trying to fetch the manager full name when a user name is populated in the people picker control. Here are the steps I am following:

1. Added another  control on page.
2. The AfterCallbackClientScript property of this control will fire a javascript method.
3. I am then getting the value of people picker control that will fetch me the Preferred Name of user.
4. This preferred name is to be used by GetUserProfileByName method to fetch user profile. But the method accepts login name and not preferred name.

Is there a way to fetch user profile from preferred name? I also want the location of user which I cannot get. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to get the managers login name and pass it back to GetUserProfileByName and get the PreferredName.

Comment: I get the preferred name from people picker form control. I want the user profile details from it. Is there a way to get user id from people picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the new SPFindPeoplePicker function in SPServices v0.7.2. It returns more information about the user(s), including the dictionary entry, which includes the account.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I've used the same function from your blog post. I guess its now a part of SPServices API library.